# Closing dialogs from another threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm having a problem with threads. My code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    cts  = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var lines = File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "urls.txt"));

    try
    {
        var q = from line in lines.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(30).WithCancellation(cts.Token)
        let result = Parse(line, cts.Token)
            select new
            {
                res = result
            };

        foreach (var x in q)
        {
            if (x != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", x.res);
            }
        }

    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
});
```

Now in Parse I have:

```
public String Parse(String url,CancellationToken ct)
{
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    /* many lines of code */
    InputForm iForm = new InputForm();
    iForm.setPageData(pageData);

    if (iForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string userInput = iForm.textBox.Text;
        /* code block */
        return result;
    } else {
        return Parse(newUrl,ct);
    }
}
```

I'm using ShowDialog because I need to get user input from iForm (this form has a timer and is auto closed after 60 seconds). Now, when I opened about 30 forms and click Cancel (on main form) this dialog forms need to be closed manualy. Is it posible to close this form after clicking Cancel?

Comment: Is this a Windows Form or WPF, and what's the "problem" an exception?

Comment: Windows Form. Problem is that I don't know how to close opened dialogs automaticaly

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, just call the `Close` method.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Calling the Close() method on a Form that is created in another thread throws an Exception.

Answer (score 1):

I do this a lot.

What you're going to need to do is

- create a way to communicate with your Main Thread Of Execution (MTOE)
- call your main thread and wait for the response
- in your main thread, display your dialog box
- set the return value for your thread
- signal your thread that you are done

A custom event handler works great for getting a message from your thread back to the MTOE.

A `ManualResetEvent` is good for your thread to know when the MTOE is complete.

A class instance can be passed in an event handler that the MTOE uses to fill a few data items and pass back to the thread whenever it is done.

Typically, when I create my special class, it contains the event handler and the `ManualResetEvent` object.

From your MTOE, if you close your form, you can signal all of your waiting dialog boxes to Cancel.

This would require a little redesign, but I think it would give you what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx

You could iterate over the open open forms and call close on those that are of type InputForm

EDIT:

The below comment is correct this would throw an exception. You would actually need something like FormToClose.BeginInvoke(delegate ()=> FormToClose.Close());

Comment: The OP's forms are created in a separate thread. If you attempt to close them from the main thread, you will receive a Cross Thread or Invalid Operation Exception.